# Replace fourth occurrence of a character in a string

Tags: r, replace

I was trying to replace fourth occurrence of '_' in a string. For example,

**Input**

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_DD_D_EEE
```

**Output**

```
AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: regex can do this easily.  I'll be back :-) with a string shortly.

Comment: I hate myself for posting this but `gsub( "(_)([^_]+)(\\1)([^_]+)(\\1)([^_]+)(\\1)" , "\\1\\2\\3\\4\\5\\6" , x , perl = TRUE )`. I am ***sure*** there are better uses of backreferences than this!

Comment: Clearly I'm misusing the word "easily" in my comment, @SimonO'Hanlon :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft it was simpler than I thought, but still feels a bit manual to me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a back-reference....

```
gsub( "(_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+)_" , "\\1" , x )
# [1] "AAA_BBB_CCC_DDD_EEE"
```

EDIT
And thanks to @SonyGeorge below this could be further simplified to:

```
gsub( "((_[^_]+){3})_" , "\\1" , x )
```

Answer (score 5):

don know in which platform you are going to use

```
pattern = (([^_]+_){3}[^_]+)_(.*)
replacement = $1.$2  // concat 1 and 2
```